# (Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility) Cluster items not being removed when Fragment is paused

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

I'm trying to implement the Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility.  The problem I was having was overlapping ClusterItems at max zoom.  My solution to this was to: Create a custom Renderer by extending DefaultClusterRenderer. Then prevent clustering at max zoom, and next to allow the ClusterItems to be draggable if at max zoom (and disallow dragging otherwise).

```
       @Override
       protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MarkerList.Markers markers, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(getImage(markers));
            Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(markers.getEntity().getPostType());

            //allow user to drag overlapping ClusterItems to inspect individually
            if(MAX_CAMERA_ZOOM <= cameraZoom){
                markerOptions.draggable(true);
            }else{
                markerOptions.draggable(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {

            //Never render clusters at max zoom
            if (MAX_CAMERA_ZOOM <= cameraZoom ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return cluster.getSize() > 2;
            }
        }
```

This will work on my phone for a little while before the clustering stops and the dragged ClusterItems become permenant so that the number of ClusterItems displayed increases(many copies of the same item are on the map).  The new dragged ClusterItems are not clickable and so I think they are only icons that are not being removed.  Can anyone help me find a solution to this?  I'm guessing I need to programmatically removed the dragged icons after dragging.  Although any suggestions to solving my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: To my understanding, you're trying to remove ClusterItems by dragging them when you're at max zoom. Maybe you could use a drag event listener and remove the ClusterItem from the map, then set the ClusterItem itself to null. Alternatively, the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276908/ shows you that you can set the max zoom level for declustering.

Comment: The problem is that the ClusterItems are overlapping each other, and so by making them draggable the user can move and inspect the hidden ones.  It's not the greatest solution but it's simple, or I thought it would be.  Is that link for java-script or android.  I think the js ultilities are further along than the Android utils.

Comment: By overlapping, do you mean that they're combining to form a bigger ClusterItem or that there's literally one ClusterItem on top of another? I think the link is for JS, sorry.  Did you try it with event listeners?

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that the issue is caused by the MapFragment getting paused and the Renderer not deleting the extra ClusterItems on the Map.  So calling map.clear in onPause seems to have fixed the issue of the extra ClusterItems.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {

    //Clear lost ClusterItems
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.clear();
    }

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}
```

This works but i'm not sure why the items are getting lost, and I guess the issue is related to pausing the MapFragment rather than dragging the ClusterItem, so i'll change the title to reflect that.