# Google Mark Cluster : Show all marker in a cluster at certain zoom level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I need to show all markers in clusters below a certain zoom level.

Here is what I [tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276908/google-markerclusterer-decluster-markers-below-a-certain-zoom-level)

```
mcOptions = {
                    minZoom: 4,
                    maxZoom: 9,
            }
```

Setting maxZoom works fine when the markers/clusters are too close. But it stuck when one marker is apart from cluster.

[image: marker declustering not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by setting minimumClusterSize to 1.

```
mcOptions = {
                minZoom: 4,
                maxZoom: 9,
                minimumClusterSize : 1
            }
```

Now it will shows all clusters or markers at one time.