# @googlemaps/markerclusterer: How to set maxZoom?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm trying to figure out how to set the maxZoom attribute.

I found the list of acceptable arguments:

```
new MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, algorithm, renderer, onClusterClick })
```

So, I don't want to implement my own algorithm. The default one I guess pretty cool.

I found the `maxZoom` property in the [documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/interfaces/AlgorithmOptions.html). But cannot understand how to pass it to the MarkerClusterer object.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276908/google-markerclusterer-decluster-markers-below-a-certain-zoom-level), but looks like the MarkerClusterer implementation have changed and the answer is outdated. The MarkerClusterer object accepts only one argument with described fields above for now.

I'll be very grateful for any help.

Comment: What a terrible/annoying/unclear documentation. Does this help? https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/issues/374 - if it doesn't, I'd require clarification on the [github issues page](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/issues).

Comment: The documentation is indeed absolutely horrible. Happy to see I'm not alone, and you provided an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck on this as well and found an easier solution. You just need to pass an object `algorithmOptions`.

```
new MarkerClusterer({map, markers, algorithmOptions: { maxZoom: 10 }});
```

I also didn't understand the docs properly but found it by looking into the source code: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/blob/e3ea80c1172eedc0f9784d832f419153a49825ce/src/markerclusterer.ts#L84C8-L84C8

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted as it looks like a more proper way to set the custom maxZoom option. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @mrupsidown for help!
The correct way to set custom `maxZoom` is to change the algorithm:

```
const algorithm = new SuperClusterAlgorithm({ maxZoom: 12 })
new MarkerClusterer({map, markers, algorithm, renderer, onClusterClick});
```